# How to transform a secondary data source inside a lookup transform?

Tags: vega-lite

How do we transform a secondary data source inside a lookup transform? I want to apply a transform inside the secondary data source itself which is `test.csv`.

Here's the `test.csv` file with few sample data

| country_txt | success |
| --- | --- |
| Australia | 1 |
| Australia | 2 |
| England | 0 |

Here's the incomplete `vega.json` file without the `mark` property but it should be enough

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "OK",
  "width": 1080,
  "height": 1080,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json",
    "format": {
      "type": "topojson",
      "feature": "countries"
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "properties.name",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "data\\test.csv"
        },
        "key": "country_txt",
        "fields": [
          "country_txt"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

I want to aggregate the counts of the countries appearing in `test.csv` before performing a lookup transform with my primary data source. So how do we do that? I tried transforming it directly before the `key` property declaration but it is not supported. I just started Vega Lite and tried reading the documentation but there's nothing I can use over there so would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "url": "data\\test.csv",
      "format": {"type": "csv", "parse": "auto"},
      "transform": [
        {"type": "aggregate","groupby":["country_txt"]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "map",
      "url": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json",
      "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "countries"},
      "transform": [
        { "type": "lookup", "from": "test", "key": "country_txt", "fields": ["properties.name"],"as":["Count"] }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Solved it by declaring my datasets inside an array of data property.